# HashMap.get() method returning null even though the element is present in the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I know there are a few questions with almost the exact same title as mine, but I looked into all of them and their solutions don't apply to my case. I am implementing a `Trie` in `Java`, and the main `Trie` class has a `HashMap` mapping `TrieNode`'s to `LinkedList`'s, resembling mapping a parent node to it's children, and another `HashMap` mapping a `LinkedList` to a `TrieNode`, to get the parent node with the children. However, in the `insert(String s)` method, the `HashMap` mapping `LinkedList`'s to `TrieNode`'s is producing a null pointer when I'm trying to use the `get()` method. I looked into this issue using the debugger, but in the debugger it said the `LinkedList` is present. Here is my code:

The main testing class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Trie trie = new Trie();
    trie.insert("abcd");
    trie.insert("abce");
    trie.insert("abc"); // When I insert "abc", it gives the error.
}
```

The `Trie` class:

```
public class Trie {

    public HashMap<TrieNode, LinkedList<TrieNode>> children;
    public HashMap<LinkedList<TrieNode>, TrieNode> nodes;

    public Trie() {
        TrieNode root = new TrieNode(' ');
        LinkedList<TrieNode> list = new LinkedList<>();

        children = new HashMap<>();
        children.put(root, list);

        nodes = new HashMap<>();
        nodes.put(list, root);
    }

    public void insert(String word) {
        TrieNode parent = new TrieNode(' ');
        TrieNode curr = null;
        LinkedList<TrieNode> children = this.children.get(parent);
        char[] chars = word.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            curr = new TrieNode(chars[i]);

            if (children.contains(curr)) {
                children = this.children.get(curr);
            } else {
                LinkedList<TrieNode> newList = new LinkedList<>();

                this.children.get(parent).add(curr);
                this.children.put(curr, newList);
                nodes.put(newList, curr);
                children = this.children.get(curr);
            }

            parent = new TrieNode(chars[i]);
        }

        if (word.equals("abc")) {
            for (LinkedList<TrieNode> currList : nodes.keySet()) {
                if (currList.equals(children)) {
                    System.out.println("Found");
                }
            }

            // I did further investigation on why it produces null on when the string "abc" is passed, and strangely enough, in my output it printed "Found".
        }

        nodes.get(children).count++; // This is where the null pointer exception occurs.
    }
}
```

The `TrieNode` class:

```
public class TrieNode {

    public char val;
    public int count;

    public TrieNode(char val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return val + "";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        TrieNode trieNode = (TrieNode) o;
        return val == trieNode.val;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(val);
    }

}
```

The error occurs when I try inserting "abc". In the `Trie` class, I tried printing "Found" if the `HashMap` contained the key when the given string is "abc", and strangely enough, it did. So the `HashMap`'s `keySet()` method contains the correct key, but it returns null when I call the `get()` method? Can someone find out what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `LinkedList` as a key to `HashMap`, and you are mutating said `LinkedList`: that's probably why you are finding the key using `keySet()` and not using `Map.get(Object)`:

```
this.children.get(parent).add(curr);
```

As an example:

```
Map<List<String>, String> map = new HashMap<>();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
map.put(list, "a"); 
System.out.println("map.get(" + list + "): " + map.get(list));
list.add("b");
System.out.println("map.get(" + list + "): " + map.get(list)); // may be null
```

The reason is quite simple:

- `HashMap` use the `hashCode()` to find the bucket were to put the value. Changing content of `List` is akin to changing `hashCode()`.
- `HashMap` then use the `equals()` to find the equivalent key. Changing content of list produce the same result.

Comment: I would drop the word _"probably"_ from _"that's probably why"_ — it most definitely **_is_** the reason.

Comment: How do you suggest I go around this problem?

Comment: @NishantChatterjeeKMS instead of putting the child/parent logic on `Trie`, put it on `TrieNode`. And don't use a collection as a key to a map. Also, the key could also be the string rather than the List: `"abc"` is not mutable, and using `Map<String, TrieNode>` is not wrong.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. I will make the children/parent logic in `TrieNode`.